# What is wrong with unsound theories? Can they be of any "practical" use?

Tags: logic, soft-question

For purposes of this post, let us restrict our attention to theories of arithmetic even though the question indeed makes sense for other theories. In what follows, assume that $PA$ is consistent.

A theory of arithmetic is said to be (arithmetically) **sound** if every statement it proves is true in the intended model $(\mathbb{N},+,\times,S,0)$. Clearly an inconsistent theory, being able to prove every statement, is unsound and is of no interest. On the other hand, by Gödel's incompleteness theorem, one can easily find unsound consistent theories extending $PA$, for example, $PA+\neg Con(PA)$.

My question is the following: Can an unsound consistent theory extending $PA$ be practically useful?

One may look at theories of sets (in particular, ZF) to see why this approach is not as meaningless as it seems at first sight. Suppose for the moment that in "the intended model of set theory", whatever that may be, ZF holds but the axiom of choice is false. There are theorems of ZF that can be proven in ZFC with an easy or short proof, for example, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815500/examples-of-theorems-that-havent-been-proven-without-ac-in-practice-but-can-be). In this imaginary scenario, ZFC is unsound but is able to prove a true statement in an easy manner by circumventing obstacles that arise from absence of choice, for example, see [the answer of Carl Mummert](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/815916/137499) on Hindman's theorem. Proving theorems via forcing (i.e. forcing absolute statements to be true in an extension) may also be seen as a set-theoretic analogue of this approach with the exception that the meaning of the word "sound" is not clear in this context.

We know that there are arithmetical analogues of this [speed-up phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_speed-up_theorem) that occur for certain sound extensions of $PA$.

Back to my question... Has anyone investigated the possible use of an unsound consistent theory of arithmetic extending $PA$ to prove statements about natural numbers that can already be proven in $PA$ with possibly long or complicated proofs? Can an unsound consistent theory of arithmetic extending $PA$ be useful in other ways?

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in paraconsistent logics?

Comment: @DanielV I don't really think paraconsistent logics are relevant to the question here. Burak's examples from set theory give cases where the end goal is **still** provability in the original (sound) theory, with the new (unsound) theory just being a simplifying detour. E.g. even if we take $\mathsf{ZF+ AD}$ as true, a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of a $\Pi^1_2$ sentence is still convincing evidence of truth to us - via Shoenfield absoluteness. I read the question as being about similar applications of "conservative/absolute speedup" in **arithmetic** *(where soundness is a somewhat "sharper" notion)*.

Comment: To the OP, I think a good first step would be to locate existing conservativity results for unsound extensions of fragments of $\mathsf{PA}$. E.g. how conservative over $\mathsf{PA}$ is $\mathsf{B\Sigma}_n+\neg \mathsf{I\Sigma}_{n+1}$? I'm sure there are known results around that somewhere. David Belanger probably knows about this; you might write to him.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Do you have a reference in mind to check out? Maybe Pudlák and Hájek? Admittedly, I am no expert on theories of arithmetic to know enough books/articles on this. (Edit: As I was writing this comment, you seem to already have added a name to contact. Thanks!)

Comment: "Do you have a reference in mind to check out?" Not really, although HP is definitely worth a look. (Incidentally, if my interpretation of your question is correct I strongly recommend shortening your question and making it more precise. In particular, the whole "objection/response" dialogue doesn't really add anything. Just point out the set theoretic examples and ask if there are arithmetic analogues.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I am on mobile right now but will try to edit those parts out later. The shorter the question the better it is, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: (edit: never mind. It seems we're limiting attention to supersets of PA-as-a-theory) So, I have a stupid question (I might be missing something obvious). The true theory of $\mathbb{N}$ is sound and consistent, but not computably axiomatizable. The true theory of $\mathbb{Z}$ would be unsound as a theory of arithmetic, but still consistent (and allowing negative numbers is practically useful in real life). Is true $\mathbb{Z}$ excluded as a potential unsound arithmetic? If so, how is it being excluded?

Comment: @GregNisbet: Perhaps I should have explicitly added that our theory includes, say, Peano or Robinson arithmetic etc. You are right that the theory of integers is unsound if considered on the natural numbers, obviously. You are also right that I was also considering theories that are somewhat true about natural numbers. I will edit.