# Which models of PA can be standard in some model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, arithmetic, model-theory, nonstandard-models

From wikipedia:

> For example, there are models of Peano arithmetic in which Goodstein's theorem fails. It can be proved in Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory that Goodstein's theorem holds in the standard model, so a model where Goodstein's theorem fails must be non-standard.

If my understanding is correct, this implies that there are models of Peano arithmetic which are not the standard natural numbers of any model of ZFC (because Goodstein's theorem must hold there). What can be said about models of Peano arithmetic that can be the standard natural numbers of some model of ZFC? Is there any simple characterization of what properties must such a model have?

Comment: I've edited my answer to incorporate Andreas' observation, which in fact fully resolves the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a surprisingly subtle question!

Right off the bat, we have an obvious observation: if $\mathcal{M}$ is a "potential $\omega$" (= is isomorphic to the $\omega$ of some model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$), then $\mathcal{M}$ must satisfy all the arithmetic consequences of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. This set of sentences, call it "$\mathsf{ZFC_{arith}}$," is not very well understood but we can prove some basic things about it; see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1992395/28111).

*That said, it's also worth noting that under a mild assumption we **can** whip up a formula that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves defines a model of $\mathsf{PA}$ which has no additional restrictions - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423328/can-we-interpret-arithmetic-in-set-theory-with-exactly-pa-as-the-zfc-provable-c/423331#423331) - but this is quite different from the usual way arithmetic is implemented in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, which you are asking about.*

But is that enough? That is, if $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC_{arith}}$, is $\mathcal{M}$ a potential $\omega$?

To see the issue, consider the following very artificial example. Let's say we replace the interesting arithmetic structure of the naturals with just the single equivalence relation "has the same parity as." Basically, this turns the naturals into two infinite blobs. Now consider a structure $\mathcal{A}$ in this language consisting of two infinite blobs of different cardinalities. Since the theory of two infinite blobs is complete, $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies everything $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves about "the naturals as a pair of blobs." However, $\mathcal{A}$ is **not** isomorphic to any model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$'s "blobby naturals." This is because the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem "the even and odd naturals have the same cardinality" *does* have consequences for the isomorphism type of "potential blobby naturals" but *is not* captured at the first-order level.

In fact, $\mathsf{ZFC_{arith}}$ falls well short of "potential $\omega$-ness" in a completely unfixable way. [Barwise/Schlipf proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2272253) the following:

> For a countable nonstandard $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{PA}$, the following are equivalent:
>
> - $\mathcal{M}$ is some $\mathsf{ZFC}$-models $\omega$.
> - $\mathcal{M}$ is **recursively saturated**.

*(Strictly speaking, they proved that any structure appearing in some non-$\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ is recursively saturated. This gives the top-to-bottom direction, with the bottom-to-top direction being folklore if I understand the history correctly. Note that countability is actually only needed in the bottom-to-top direction!)*

The omitting types theorem then prevents *any* first-order theory from capturing potential $\omega$-ness. (Thanks to Andreas Blass for pointing this out to me in the comments below!) Depending on whether you like recursive saturation, this may or may not answer your question in the specific case of *countable* models. Unfortunately (or interestingly), *un*countable models pose much more difficulties, and I believe no characterization is currently known even of the size-$\aleph_1$ models of $\mathsf{PA}$ which are isomorphic to some $\mathsf{ZFC}$-models' version of the naturals. (But that shouldn't be too surprising, since even the ordertypes of size-$\aleph_1$ models of $\mathsf{PA}$ aren't classified yet.)

---

As a coda, I vaguely recall an old paper (by H. Friedman?) on the following problem: given a first-order theory $T$, when does a tuple of formulas $\Phi$ have the property that, if we let $T_\Phi$ be the set of sentences $T$ proves holds of the structure interpreted by $\Phi$, then for all $\mathcal{A}\models T_\Phi$ there is some $\mathcal{B}\models T$ with $\mathcal{A}\cong \Phi^\mathcal{B}$? Basically, these $\Phi$s should not be "missing" any structural data (e.g. the "blobby naturals" example above was missing the structural data of the $n\mapsto n+1$ bijection). I can't seem to find the paper at the moment, however. My recent mathoverflow questions [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433486/can-we-always-sharpen-interpretations), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433687/when-can-interpretations-be-optimized?noredirect=1&lq=1) address this general theme, current absence of a reference notwithstanding.

Comment: It seems to me that, if a countable morel of the arithmetic consequences of ZFC is recursively saturated,  then it should be the $\omega$ of a model of ZFC, essentially because countable recursively saturated models are resplendent.

Comment: Since I don't have time now to check any of this carefully, I might as well add that, for nonstandard (in the real world) models, recursive saturation should also be a necessary condition for being the $\omega$ of a ZFC model, and that this should be in the original Barwise-Schlipf paper on recursive saturation. (All occurrences of "should" here mean "I think this is true but I haven't checked carefully.")

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, I think I agree; that just leaves the uncountable recursively saturated case.

Comment: @AndreasBlass BTW does my last paragraph ring a bell? (I'm somewhat tempted to ask about it as a separate question.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I've (very belatedly) incorporated your comments, thanks!